# login to .net core app with different email and username

Tags: .net-core, identity

I was building dot net core web app but identity system does not allow me to login.I figured that if my username and email address in database would not be the same it wont logged in.Anyone knows what is going on??

Comment: Are you trying to login with your username instead of your email? Then you have to adjust the code in `AccountControler.Login` to find the user either by email or by username.

Comment: I mean i built a dot net core web app with individual authentication selected,i changed register Post register action to save username something other than email.after registration user logs in,every body happy but if user log off and try to login with the same credential again that would fail

Comment: Can you update the answer with both your `Register` and `Login` methods?

Comment: i guess their too long for comment or maybe i do not know how to add code in comments.by the way in register action i am using     await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);      and in login action the line is     await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the following login method on an account controller allows logins with either the username or the password:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody]LoginPost model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    // The user is identified either by Email or by Username
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Identifier)
            ?? await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Identifier);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }
    var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, true, false);
    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
    return Unauthorized();
 }
```

Please note the line where the user is looked up in the backing store: `FindByEmail() ?? FindByUsername`. This allows you to login with either `username/password` or `email/password`.